# sequlizejs WHERE `where` in query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequlizejs and mysql for database.I am trying to update row using where clause.This is the code i am using

```
Student.update({
            name: 1,
            address: 1,
            email: 1,
            course_id: 1
        }, {
            where: {
                student_id: 1
            }
        }).success(onSuccess).error(onError);
```

But this is returning this

```
 UPDATE `students` SET `name`=1,`address`=1,`email`=1,`course_id`=1 WHERE `where`  1
```

This query has syntax error at the end.Desired query is.

```
 UPDATE `students` SET `name`=1,`address`=1,`email`=1,`course_id`=1 WHERE `student_id` = 1
```

My sequlizejs version is sequelize@1.7.11.
Can anybody help me to correct my error.

Answer (score 1):

Is it mandatory that you use Sequelize@1.7.11 ? This library is currently at its version [3.4.1](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md) and they updated the UPDATE/WHERE clause in [2.0.2](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md#202).

(See this issue on Github: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3113)